# Run Activity from beginning

Tags: android

I have application which when start I run `MainActivity` and after get some data I choose which next activity should be started. I have a problem with something like that: when I start first time `MainActivity` start and choose correct activity. When I am in correct activity and use home button and choose again application from menu Application start not from `MainActivity` but from my correct activity. How can I start my application always from `MainActivity` even if I use home button to hide application to background and chose from menu button again my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply override `onResume()` in your other Activity and finish your current Activity and start MainActivity

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


        Intent startAct= new Intent(OtherActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(startAct);
        finish();
    }
```